# How to block a window as if Dialog window was displayed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a form which I would like to block during execution of an async event. I would like to achieve an effect similar to when a dialog window is displayed, without displaying or creating one.

I don't want to manually disable controls on the form, as some controls may be added in the future (not necessarily by me). I would like to avoid disabling the entire form / user control for aesthetic reasons.

Is there a standard/elegant way of achieving this, or am I going in a wrong direction?

Comment: Just wait on the async event - UI events (typing etc) will be queued until  done.

Comment: @BensaysNotoPoliticsonSO You mean wait synchronously? The event in the worst case could take a few minutes to finish, so it may look like the application is not responding.

Comment: Really you should give some feedback. Show a modal form which doesn't have any way to dismiss it, e.g. no cancel or close button.

Comment: I was going to display feedback on the form itself. I suppose I could make modal window invisible.

Comment: OK well one option is to put all the major controls into a panel, then set the panel.enabled = false.

Comment: Having disabled controls without any notification about the reason why will be same experience for user as having not responding form during synchronous execution. You need inform user about long running task - having modal message will be one option, second option make controls enable/disable in the loop `Controls.ForEach(control => control.Enabled = false)`

Comment: @Fabio "I was going to display feedback on the form itself". Thanks though. I usually try to avoid creating long lived modal windows, as sometimes they get covered which may be annoying to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can block WinForm window by setting it's `Enabled` property to `false`, but it will prevent user from any action with that window (like moving, resizing or hiding) and it may be very annoying. Consider showing some load indicator instead.

I would not recommend to disable controls without making them look disabled because it could confuse user.

**Edit:** As @AvoNappo pointed out window behavior differs depend on where to set `Enable` property to `false`:

- if you set it in the constructor user still will be able to move/minimize/close window;
- if you call it after constructor window control buttons and windows movement also will be blocked.

Comment: Also, there is a subtle difference, where you out that Enabled = false. In form constructor, it seems to disable all child controls, but you can still move  and close the form itself. When you put it in Load handler, it basically blocks everything, so same effect as if a modal dialog had popped.

Comment: This seems to grey out all subcontrols while with a modal window controls look normal. But I may have to resort to this if I cannot find anything better. ("I would like to avoid disabling the entire form / user control for aesthetic reasons" )

Comment: @user5226582 I've added second option that uses same method as modal window while opening

Comment: Good point that inactive controls which don't look disabled may be confusing, so I will probably disable the entire user control after all. Thanks!

Comment: @user5226582 sorry this is a mistake on my side, this method indeed called on showing modal but it does't block window, I'll search for another solution.

Comment: Don't worry about it - I think the first option is more correct after all. Thanks again!

Comment: @user5226582, seems odd that accepted answer do exact oposite what you asked for  ;) _I would like to avoid disabling the entire form_

Comment: @Fabio I think I got my answer to this "Is there a standard/elegant way of achieving this, or am I going in a wrong direction?". Also, I can always unaccept and accept a different answer.